# Multi Dimensional numerical integration in Julia

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I was trying to find a way to numerically integrate an array of values `phi1::Vector{Float64}` of y-values, and the input space is given by the three arrays `x,y,z` all defined as `range(-1,stop=1,length=100)`.

I tried using `HCubature.jl` package, but it requires a `::Function` and all I have is the array. It's like there is some function phi(x,y,z) which we do not know analytically. Thus we we have an array `phi` where `phi1[i]` stores the value of `phi(x[i],y[i],z[i])`

The integration has to be performed in an entirely numeric fashion without any idea of the origin of the `phi1` values.

Comment: You're likely going to need to write a routine on your own for such a limited setting. I would doubt the quality of your result as well... if there's a way you could write a routine for which you could sample your points (eg, how did you get your `phi1` to start?), that might work with hcubature, but that package relies on being able to sample more and more points.

Comment: Perhaps (untested) trying first to fit the data using a generic nonlinear fitting package, e.g.  [`LsqFit`](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages like HCubature are designed to integrate functions `f(p)` that you can evaluate at *arbitrary* points p (e.g. you have an analytic expression for `f(p)`, or more generally some program that can compute `f(p)` at arbitrary `p`).   This is by *far* the most efficient way to do numerical integration.

If, instead, you have data for the function evaluated on some fixed set of points, e.g. a Cartesian grid, then typically people use low-order methods like the trapezoidal rule — you can use the [Trapz.jl](https://github.com/francescoalemanno/Trapz.jl) package, for example, which already supports the multi-dimensional trapezoidal rule.

(The best method depends on where your data came from.  If it's from a finite-difference algorithm, for example, ideally you would use a integration algorithm of the same order of accuracy as your FD method.)